# Switching GPIOs on and off

Tags: gpio

I have built a system that uses a pulsed 3.3v output to control solenoids. i have all the paeriherals in place but am struggling to define how to simply switch the power on and off on my raspberry Pi 3. I have done no set up whastover on the Pi (except turn it on) so need a basic idea of what i needd to install and then a simplexamle code of how to swicth the GPIO on and off, can anyone help?

Comment: a search for blink LED and whatever language you are using will give you what you need. I realize you are not trying to blink an LED but conceptually they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Are you programming in Python?
If so google 'switch gpio on and off in python', there are lots of copy and paste bits of code with lots of better explanation than I can write here.
Hope it helps. As i few months ago I stuggled with the same thing. but have it working now in Python.